# Need to convert comma separated string into json string

Tags: javascript, json, powershell

I will get email id's as comma separated string  `(recipient1@example.com,recipient2@example.com,recipient3@example.com )`.
How can I build json string like this by using power shell

```
{"personalizations": [
{"to": [
    {"email": "recipient1@example.com"},
    {"email": "recipient2@example.com"}
]}]}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split input string with the `String.Split()` method, then construct an object that looks like the desired JSON and finally pipe through `ConvertTo-Json`:

```bsh
$recipients = "recipient1@example.com,recipient2@example.com,recipient3@example.com"

@{
  personalizations = @(
    @{
      to = @(
        $recipients.Split(',').ForEach({@{email=$_}})
      )
    }
  )
} |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```